# Trouble simulating Colpitts in Multisim

Tags: simulation, oscillator, multisim

I've been trying to get a Colpitts oscillator to work with multisim, following this schematic, which I found in a book (I just copied it):

[image]

Yet, it does not work, all I get is a 0 voltage signal from the oscilloscope.

The same circuit, simulated in LTSpice, worked fine:

[image]

So, does anyone with experience in multisim know how to get this simulation to work? A similar oscillator in the "examples -> miscellaneus circuits -> claposcillator" works great, adn the book where I found it also simulated it in Multisim and according to it, simulation works fine as well (book is Electronic devices eighth edition, by Floyd, page 84X)

Here are some of the things I've tried:

- Add a AC voltage source with low voltage to simulate noise
- Change the values of the capacitors to the ones in the LTSpice figure
- Try different transistors and components

Comment: Are you sure your 12V connection is actually made?

Comment: Yes.. the error that comes with that red circle is:
Error: Connecting Bidirectional to Power: [R3 pin, ....]
I've looked it up and it seems to be some sort of Electrical Rules Check setting

Comment: Though now that you mentioned it, that same check error doesn't come with the simulations that actually work... hm, I'll look into that right now
EDIT: yea, same exact settings, now I'm 100% clueless

Comment: For some reason all the resistors and capacitors were "bidirectional". I changed them all to "passive", and there were no errors in the design check. 
Unfortunately, the same problem ensued...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same circuit on the emitter. You've got a 1k pot in series with a 1k resistor and the pot wiper connects to a grounding capacitor. You've also got a 10pF cap where it is 100nF in LTSpice.

I'm not saying any of these matter but you can't possibly make comparisons with these glaring disparities.

**EDIT**

Following comments from the OP, the problem I think arises from the new "intended" operating frequency of the circuit (he uses a 10pF cap on the multisim circuit to set the resonant frequency whilst the LTSpice circuit has 100nF). Added to this is the lack of emitter capacitor - the multisim circuit shows it connected via the wiper of a pot set midway and this will drastically reduce the gain and prevent or delay oscillation. Remember that the collector has to generate enough signal to drive the 10nF capacitor (C3) and at a much higher frequency this 10nF (via C5, 1uF) will probably look like a short circuit - the gain of the transistor has to be greater than 1 for it to begin oscillation and with no directly connected emitter capacitor and a 10nF effectively connected to the collector I think the gain will be less than unity.

I'm not totally familiar with this type of Colpitts oscillator but it seems to me that the LTSpice circuit should oscillate at about 41kHz whereas the MS circuit should operate at about 4.1MHz - this isn't going to happen with a 10pF - its reactance at 4.1MHz will be nearly 4 kohms and this will get "battered" by R1 and R2 in the imedance versus resistance race. Do the sensible thing and start with the same circuit. On the LT circuit, the 100nF will have an impedance of about 40 ohms at 41kHz and therefore not be hardly affected by R1 and R2.

Comment: I didn't change them because they should still give me an oscillation, but with different frequencies and gain. 
In any case, to be sure, I've changed the circuit to exactly the one in LTSpice, and the same problem occurred

Comment: have you tried letting the circuit run for up to a second just to check that it definitely doesn't oscillate after a few hundred milliseconds. Colpitts can be slow starters and I've hit this problem on my simulator.

Comment: I'd also make the component values the same because that 10pF cap may prefer having lighter base bias resistors. Make the emitter the same too because at the moment, your gain will be drastically reduced with the wiper set central.

Comment: So I got it to work, and that I had to:
1) Set a lower time-step, for some reason the automatic one didn't help
2) Remove the potentiometer. It's funny that I found this in a book, and I triple-checked that it's exctly like the book schematic. When I redid the circuit it still didn't work because 
3) It "still had a "bidirectional" capacitor instead of a "passive one"(whatever that means..), so I had to replace it.

Lot's of things going wrong but at least I see the blessed sine wave.

Comment: The osc frequency seen is 130khz.. if you substitute into the colpitts formula you get 137kHz, so it seems close enough.

Could you explain why the gain is drastically reduced with the pot? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this

Comment: @triplebig BJT gain (simplified explanation) is collector impedance divided by emitter impedance. The cap directly on the emitter means the emitter impedance is quite low which means there is a good chance the gain is > unity. BTW are the oscillation frequencies based on formula or just the simulation? Also what formula did you use (just for my benefit)

Comment: so basically the pot adds more impedance to the emitter in such a way that the gain becomes less than unity?
Also, the formula I used it 2pi*f = 1/sqrt(L*C_T), where C_T is C3||C4

Comment: Exactly - what frequency did you see in multisim - I'm not sure the formula you have used is correct. C3 and C4 are not particularly related let alone in // - I'd have thought C2 would have set the frequency - maybe you have a link you can share?

Comment: Awesome, got it!
The formula for that particular circuit is in the book I referenced in my post, but it seems there are a ton of colpitt variations, but they all have the same formula. Here's one, for instance:
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/colpitts.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in past.
Try other transistor.
Adjust Time Step (low values).
Make capacitors and inductors have any initial value.